# Clickable image grid in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, image-gallery

If this is a dumb question, forgive me. I have a small amount of experience with C#, but not to this degree yet.

I have a series of images that I want to put into a grid with space around each image, also text beneath them and I want them to be clickable, so when they're clicked they hilite, and double click runs an event. The best example I have for this is the user interface of the program `ACDSee`. I've googled this for hours, and haven't come up with anything applicable. Is this difficult or simple? Can anyone give me an example, or point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Comment: picturebox has click event and padding property.. when you set click event it works just as the same with button..and if you want to set a space between image and picturebox border set the padding property..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be very difficult. I would suggest the following steps:

1. Add a new "User Control" to your project for image thumbnails. It can contain a docked `PictureBox` and a `Label` or `LinkLabel` at its bottom.
2. For the space around each thumbnail simply play with the `Padding` property of the user control.
3. For the so called grid that is going to hold the thumbnails, use a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and simply add instances of the above mentioned user-control to this panel.
4. For visual representation of being selected, change the background color of the user-control instance to blue (for example), and back to control-face when deselected. It is recommended to implement an `IsSelected` property for the user-control as well.
5. To emulate thumbnail selection, handle the `Click` event of the user-control and assign the events for all thumbnail instances to a *single event-handler method*. Store a global reference to the already selected thumbnail, name it e.g., `SelectedThumbnail` initialized with null. In the event-handler body compare the `sender` with the global `SelectedThumbnail`, and update it if required. If the user-control associated with the `sender` is not selected (i.e., its background is not blue, or `IsSelected` is `false`) make it selected, or change its background. Otherwise change the background to its default color (e.g., control-face).

The `Click` event handler body looks something like this:

```
MyThumbnailControl ctrl = sender as MyThumbnailControl;
if(ctrl == null) return;
if(ctrl == SelectedThumbnail) return; // selected again
if(ctrl != SelectedThumbnail)
{
    ctrl.IsSelected = true;
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Blue; 
    // it's better to set the back-color in the IsSelected property setter, not here
    SelectedThumbnail.IsSelected = false;
    SelectedThumbnail.BackColor = Color.Control;
    SelectedThumbnail = ctrl; // important part
}
```

It's also recommended that all thumbnail instances that are going to be added to the so-called grid, be referenced in a separate array too. Therefore changing selection with arrow-keys would be possible with simple index calculations.

---

Further Notes: I assumed that the user-control that is to be created is named `MyThumbnailControl`, just a random name to refer to that control. When you create a new user-control, the wizard generates a class for you with your desired name (e.g., `MyThumbnailControl`), you can define a property inside it named `IsSelected` and implement its getter and setter. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a tutorial. After defining the user-control you can instantiate instances from its corresponding class. Also by global reference, I meant a variable at the form (or any parent control) level. To keep it simple we can add a reference of the selected thumbnail in the form that is going to hold the grid and thumbnails: `MyThumbnailControl selectedThumb = null;` or something like this in the body of the form.

Comment: Cheers, this was exactly what I needed. :) Next question: How can I make it selectable? E.g. When I click on it, it has a blue background? Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Couple of small questions though: when you say `It is recommended to implement an IsSelected property for the user-control as well.` How do you mean? Also, `MyThumbnailControl`, what is it? How would I initialize it etc? Sorry if these seem like noob questions, it's just because I am actually a noob :P

Comment: Also, how do I `Store a global reference to the already selected thumbnail`?

Comment: @Spiritfyre because of character limitation in comments, I added further explanations in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared it up a lot for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Last question: `It's also recommended that all thumbnail instances that are going to be added to the so-called grid, be referenced in a separate array too. Therefore changing selection with arrow-keys would be possible with simple index calculations.` How would I do this? I know I'm asking a lot, but I can't rack my brains to figure out how to do this. Any help would be hugely appreciated. I already have the math for the indexing, I just need to be able to select them.

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something, I just fixed you.

Create a C# project name **CreateImageList** and in the Form1  add the following 5 controls with their default name i.e. Panel1, PictureBox1, Label1, Button1, Button2:

[image]

How it works:

1. When the page load it create an imageList objects and load all .jpg images from a folder you provide
2. ImageList Images are set into the PictureBox control and when user clicks "Button1" the picturebox shows next image in ImageList and when user clicks "Button2" the PictureBox shows previous image from ImageList.
3. The Label1 shows the currentImage counter from the ImageList Arrage. If you want to write something specific, you can create an array of text and sync with your image counter.
4. When user click on PictureBox the a border is create to show Picture highlighted
5. When user Double Click on PictureBox a MessageBox appears shows DoubleClick event.

Now, you can use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CreateImageList
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int currentImage = 0;
    protected Graphics myGraphics;
    ImageList iPicList = new ImageList();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DirectoryInfo dirImages = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\2012");
        iPicList.ImageSize = new Size(255, 255);
        iPicList.TransparentColor = Color.White;
        myGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(panel1.Handle);

        foreach (FileInfo file in dirImages.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Extension == ".jpg")
            {
                Image myImage = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                iPicList.Images.Add(myImage);
            }
        }

        if (iPicList.Images.Empty != true)
        {
            panel1.Refresh();
            currentImage = 0;
            // Draw the image in the panel.
            iPicList.Draw(myGraphics, 1, 1, currentImage);
            // Show the image in the PictureBox.
            pictureBox1.Image = iPicList.Images[currentImage];
            label1.Text = "Image #" + currentImage;
        }

    }

    private void showImage(int imgIndex)
    {
        // Draw the image in the panel.
        iPicList.Draw(myGraphics, 1, 1, currentImage);
        // Show the image in the PictureBox.
        pictureBox1.Image = iPicList.Images[currentImage];
        label1.Text = "image #" + currentImage;
        panel1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (iPicList.Images.Count - 1 > currentImage)
        {
            currentImage++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        showImage(currentImage);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (iPicList.Images.Count - 1 >= currentImage)
        {
            if (currentImage == 0)
                currentImage = iPicList.Images.Count-1;
            else
                currentImage--;
        }
        else
        {
            currentImage = iPicList.Images.Count;
        }
        showImage(currentImage);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Picture Box Double clicked");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Refresh();
        myGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, iPicList.Images[currentImage].Width + 1, iPicList.Images[currentImage].Height + 1);
        pictureBox1.Image = iPicList.Images[currentImage];
    }
}
}
```

The changes you need are:

Change the Following folder to a place where you have lots of jpg:

```
DirectoryInfo dirImages = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\2012");
```

Also if you are dealing with other kind of images, make change here:

```
if (file.Extension == ".jpg") // Change it to your image type.
```

If you don't want to use the the buttons to go up and down, you have several other options to host PictureBox control in scrollable Panel or list or something else.

Comment: Good looking code, but not what I asked for. I was specifically asking for a "Clickable image grid" This is neither a grid, nor are the images clickable. Thankyou for helping, but please read the question.